# google cloud restore sshd_config

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, sshd

I have fucked up my /etc/ssh/sshd_config on a google cloud compute engine VM instance. So I can no longer connect via ssh. Is there a way to restore the file and regain ssh access other than starting all over again?

I added the following line to the file. I thought It would set the default folder for testuser to testfolder when the user connects via sftp.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -u testuser -l INFO -d /mnt/disks/testfolder
```

And I commented out the line

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

I guess I shouldn't have done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to modify the file:

1) [Connecting to the VM using the serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).  I believe this will only work if you have setup already a password for your user. Then you will be able to log in and edit the file. Other details can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#interacting_with_the_serial_console).

2) Following a similar approach to the one in the section “[Inspect an instance without shutting it down](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#ssherrors)”. Which basically would imply:

- a) [Delete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/delete) the VM but making sure to keep the disk (--keep-disk=all).If you want to go on the safe side, you could also take a [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) of the disk and make a [new disk from it](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create).

  b) [Spin a new VM](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) that can normally boot

  c) [Attach the failing disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) or its copy to this new VM

  d) Mount the attached disk on Linux FS.

  e) Edit the SSH configuration file.

  f) Detach the disk.

  g) Spin a new VM using the modified disk.

Comment: Thanks, 1) always prompted me for a password, so I went with 2).